# Why does this script get a parsing error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't really know C# too well at the moment; I'm just being tossed through a crash course on Unity at light speed.

I tried to drag and drop this script from my desktop to the assets folder in the Unity project view, but it said "Parsing error 1,13". I'm not sure what's wrong with the script. Can someone with a more experienced eye glance it over?

```
var emitter : ParticleEmitter = GetComponentsInChildren(Partic­­leEmitter);

if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")){ emitter.emit=true;

}

else{

emitter.emit=false;

}
```

Comment: You seem to have a special character between the `c` and the `l` of the second occurence of `ParticleEmitter` on the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used Unity w/ C# myself but I can tell you that your script isn't even valid C# syntax. C# variables are typed in one of two ways:

- Implicitly: `var x = SomeExpression;` where x automatically takes on the type of the expression
- Explicitly: `ParticleEmitter x = SomeExpression;` where x is a `ParticleEmitter` and the expression is required to be of the same type.

The error, specifically, is compaining about the `:` in your first line. That's illegal C# syntax as the only character that can legitimately appear in that position is `=`.

Comment: I'M AN IDIOT. IT'S JAVASCRIPT. I WASN'T THINKING. I realized this instantly as soon as I read your first sentence. Those are the two viable Unity languages, and this script was online without a language tag and I just blindly assumed without thinking. So silly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not C#, this is written in UnityScript (which is based off of JavaScript).

You can tell this because the ":" colon character is used as type declaration in UnityScript, but is not valid in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Never used C# myself but I'd try implicit type declaration by leaving out the ": ParticleEmitter" part in the first line...

Answer (score 0):

GetComponentsInChildren() returns the type of Component. The parsing error is probably from the compiler trying to reconcile passing a `Component` type to a `ParticleEmitter` type.

This example from the Unity3D docs for `Component.GetComponentsInChildren` should help you out:

```
 // Disable the spring on all HingeJoints 
 // in this game object and all its child game objects
 var hingeJoints : Component[];
 hingeJoints = GetComponentsInChildren (HingeJoint);
 for (var joint : HingeJoint in hingeJoints) {
     joint.useSpring = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As CC Inc has stated the code you've provided is not C#

i've attempted to convert it for you:

```
ParticleEmitter emitter = GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleEmitter>().FirstOrDefault();

if (emitter != null)
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        emitter.emit = true;
    }
    else
    {
        emitter.emit = false;
    }
}
```

the GetComponentsInChildren returns an array. as such to mimic what you've got above i've stated that i want the first one, if you can't find any give me the default (which is null).

this may not be what you require you may want something alone the lines of:

```
bool fire = Input.GetButton("Fire1");
ParticleEmitter[] emitters = GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleEmitter>();
foreach(ParticleEmitter emitter in emitters)
{
    emitter.emit = fire; 
}
```

the above will store the boolean result of Input.GetButton, then loop through all the emitters that it has found and set them to the same value as Input.Getbutton.

obviously the above is all just guessing at what you want, i hope it helps.